# Is there a free profinite abelian group on a profinite set?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, profinite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $\mathit{Profinite}_{\mathrm{Ab}}$ be the category of profinite abelian groups, and let $\mathit{Profinite}_{\mathrm{Set}}$ be the category of profinite sets. Does the forgetful functor

$$\mathit{Profinite}_{\mathrm{Ab}} \to \mathit{Profinite}_{Sets}$$

admit a left adjoint?

I am a beginner to this kind of question; I do not even know if both the domain and codomain categories admit all small colimits.

Comment: Changed using "mathit", which corrects "$Profinite$" to "$\mathit{Profinite}$".

Comment: Just using the universal properties, one sees that the profinite completion $G_I$ of the free abelian group $\mathrm{Z}^{(I)}$ is naturally the free profinite abelian group over the set $I$, in the sense that every map $I\to H$ for $H$ a profinite abelian group uniquely extends to a continuous homomorphism $G_I\to H$. (I see this is not the asked question, this is just a remark.)

Comment: To adapt to the question, I guess that $I$ being profinite, one can start from $\mathbf{Z}^{(I)}$ and call a congruence subgroup, a subgroup $L$ of finite index such that the composed map $I\to \mathbf{Z}^{(I)}/L$ factors through some finite quotient of the profinite set $I$. Then the pro-congruence completion of $\mathbf{Z}^{(I)}$ (which is a quotient of the profinite completion) ought to be the required free profinite abelian group over the profinite set $I$.

Comment: I think for some profinite set $S = \varprojlim S_i$, you can take $\varprojlim_i \widehat{\mathbb Z}[S_i]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the free functor (i.e. the left adjoint to the "forgetful" functor) exists.

Let $Ab^{fin}$ be the category of finite abelian groups and $Set^{fin}$ the category of finite sets. Because each of these categories are essentially small and have finite limits, the categories of [pro-objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pro-object) $Pro(Ab^{fin})$ and $Pro(Set^{fin})$ are complete and cocomplete. In fact, they are opposite to [locally finitely presentable categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+finitely+presentable+category) -- if $C$ is essentially small with finite limits then $Pro(C) \simeq Fun^{lex}(C,Set)^{op}$ where $Fun^{lex}$ denotes the category of finite-limit-preserving functors. So equivalently, we're asking whether the forgetful functor $Fun^{lex}(Ab^{fin}, Set) \to Fun^{lex}(Set^{fin}, Set)$ has a right adjoint.

The forgetful functor $U_!: Fun^{lex}(Ab^{fin}, Set) \to Fun^{lex}(Set^{fin}, Set)$ is by definition the left Kan extension $Lan_{y_{Ab^{fin}}} (y_{Set^{fin}}\circ U^{op})$ where $y_C: C^{op} \to Fun^{lex}(C,Set)$ is the co-Yoneda embedding and $U: Ab^{fin} \to Set^{fin}$ is the forgetful functor. If we look at the full presheaf categories $Fun(C,Set)$ rather than $Fun^{lex}(C,Set)$, [the right adjoint to this exists and is given by the functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion) $U^\ast: Fun(Set^{fin},Set) \to Fun(Ab^{fin}, Set)$ given by precomposition by the forgetful functor $U: Ab^{fin} \to Set^{fin}$.

Since $U: Ab^{fin} \to Set^{fin}$ preserves finite limits, $U^\ast$ restricts to a functor $Fun^{lex}(Set^{fin}, Set) \to Fun^{lex}(Ab^{fin}, Set)$, and because $Fun^{lex}$ is a full subcategory of $Fun$, the same calculation as at the link above shows that this functor is the adjoint we are searching for.

Comment: Why does Fun^{lex} admit all small colimits? I understand it admits filtered colimits (which commute with finite limits in Set) but how do I compute a finite colimit in Fun^{lex}?

Comment: @ProfiniteQuestioner It is a reflective category of the presheaf category.

Comment: I am missing something basic here. Do you conclude the existence of the left adjoint (to the inclusion of Fun^{lex} into Fun) by (i) constructing it (if so, how?), or by (ii) proving that Fun^{lex} admits all small colimits (if so, how?) and invoking the adjoint functor theorem, or (iii) exhibiting Fun^{lex} of a localization of Fun along certain morphisms (if so, how?). I am sorry these are such basic questions.

Comment: Using the profinite completion of the free abelian group as suggested by @YCor, seems a simpler solution.

Comment: @ProfiniteQuestioner Where are you learning about profinite groups and profinite sets? Do they not cover such facts? My reference is Adamek and Rosicky's _Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories_, though that's not the most direct reference

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Perhaps, but the description given above is exceedingly simple: the "free" functor, regarded as a functor $Fun^{lex}(Set^{fin}, Set)^{op} \to Fun^{lex}(Ab^{fin}, Set)^{op}$, is just precomposition with the forgetful functor $U: Ab^{fin} \to Set^{fin}$.